# I'm unable to insert XML into Quickbooks with help of web connector

Tags: java, spring, quickbooks, qbxml

The XML ledger tag have the special character value, because of this reason I'm unable to insert into quickbooks.

The ledger tag value is

```
<FullName>4000 · Inventory Asset:4002 · Finished Assembly</FullName>
```

and the qb web connector log is

> message="QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream."

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help:

```xml
    <FullName>
        <![CDATA[
            4000 · Inventory Asset:4002 · Finished Assembly
        ]]>
    </FullName>
```

Comment: I have tried this one. then also I am getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

The accounts in QuickBooks *display* a special character, but they *do not actually include a special character in the data*.

If you actually edit the account in QuickBooks, you'll see that the account has *two separate fields* in it:

1. `Name = Inventory Asset`
2. `AccountNumber = 4000`

Your qbXML should look like this:

`<FullName>Inventory Asset:Finished Assembly</FullName>`